# Realtime Image Stream in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner web developer and I've spent so many hours trying to just do the following simple thing and have gotten nowhere... :( can someone help?

every 5-10 seconds, a file called latest_event.png will be updated on my computer with new contents. Using Python's Flask server, I just want to have my client application periodically poll my server and render the latest image in a web browser. I also want the user to be able to check and uncheck a box and their selection should be sent back to the server and their choice will affect how I render the latest_event.png image.

Alternatively, I've also explored Flask Socket IO libraries, but can't seem to get them working with image passing.

Would someone save the day and share with me the barebones server and client code to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need flask. Just serve the image from a webserver.

Comment: I'm more comfortable in Python and Flask was recommended to me. The image isn't static...I'm hoping someone can help me with barebones code to either poll for the image or push via Pythons Flask-SocketIO library

Comment: If all you're doing is serving a page with the image, you can do everything with HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
@app.route('/latest_event.png')
def latest_event():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'latest_event.png',
                           mimetype='image/png')
```

You can put your image into a folder named 'static' and push it out through flask this way.